# places Autocomplete return incorrect coordinates

Tags: autocomplete, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-places-api

Yesterday I found weird problem in Places Autocomplete feature. I couldn't find solution so I start over from the begining.

I check google example:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Using example I found this place:

**23847, Bad Oldesloe, Niemcy**

at coordinates: 53.7459271,10.483967699999994 (which is wrong).

When I did exactly the same at https://maps.google.com marker appears in different place. At 53.806505,10.374177. Distance between this two places is more than 10km.

In addition my client reported me that he found location where difference is about 800km !!!

Does anybody know what cause it? Or how to fix it? It looks like api problem for me but I'm rather new in Google API so I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know what results google uses inside their maps-implementation.
I guess it's a mixing of geocoding and places.  You may request the location via [**geocoding**](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q=23847,%20Bad%20Oldesloe,%20Niemcy) and will see that you get the desired result.